# Connecting to SQL with PS, Drive Not Found

Tags: sql, powershell

I am attempting to pipe the results of a SQL query into a .txt file on the local server.
Not sure what the command is missing.

```
$sqlpeeps = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '192.168.1.1' -Database 'DATABASE' -Query "SELECT 'FILE#' AS 
'EmployeeID' FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[employee] WHERE 'v_employee.Status' in ('A', 'S', 'L')"

$sqlpeeps | out-file {"C:\Users\<my username>\Desktop\here.txt"}
```

Comment: Remove the curly braces from `Out-File`.  PowerShell is interpreting that as a script block which isn't going to work.  Not sure if that's your whole problem, but let me know how far that gets you.

Comment: I've removed the curly braced and, like you said, it cleared up the issue. The script now runs without an error but isn't returning any data. I may need to double check the server, database, and columns i am using. thank you!

Comment: Hi again Steven.

I've ironed out the kinks with the SQL query accuracy, but something still doesn't seem to be right. The code is running without an error but the file I'm creating seems to have no data. Am I missing a piece to pull the data from the query into powershell's pipe?

Comment: I haven't used `Invoke-SQLcmd` I usually use the System.Data.SqlClient and .Adapter namespaces to do queries.  It's a few more lines of code but works well and I don't have to worry about which modules are installed.  That said, not knowing your data I don't see anything wrong with your query, if there are results it should return them.  As a diagnostic try broadening the query, remove the Where clause.  This will tell you if it's working.  Also, if you have access to the server try test/dev-ing in SQL studio. Let me know if you want a .net example.